# Is there a way to do a WeakList or WeakCollection (like WeakReference) in CLR?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, weak-references

Using a `List<WeakReference>` will not work as I want. What I want is for WeakReferences to be automatically *removed from the list* whenever the object they reference is garbage collected.

`ConditionalWeakTable<TKey,TValue>` does not satisfy me either, because although its keys and values are weakly referenced and collectable, you cannot enumerate them!

Comment: Interesting to see two answers so far both have some not-fully-automatic purge step. I need to spend some time thinking about it but it might actually be good enough for what I need even if its not fully automatic.

Comment: Purging is most naturally done during enumeration. The only other option is to have a periodic purging, in which case the solution becomes more of a "cache" than a "weak List". `WeakReference` is not supposed to be used for caching; there are better solutions for that (e.g., [System.Runtime.Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.aspx)).

Comment: Thanks for the interesting suggestion about System.Runtime.Caching. But I had a particular application in mind for this question, and I can see some impedence mismatches - 1) I don't need or want to use string keys to get items, I just want to be able to iterate them on demand. 2) I would probably be happier if items only leave the cache due to being garbage collected, and not for other miscellaneous reasons (like cache using too much memory).

Comment: Here's how to do it. [See this StackOverflow answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62583756/4379238)

Comment: For reference: [`Nito.Mvvm.WeakCollection<T>` by Stephen Cleary](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Mvvm/blob/master/src/Nito.Mvvm.Core/WeakCollection.cs) | [`Roslyn.Utilities.WeakList<T>` by Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/src/Compilers/Core/Portable/InternalUtilities/WeakList.cs)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I agree that implementing a `WeakList<T>` is possible, but I don't think it's exactly *easy*. You're welcome to use my implementation [here](https://github.com/StephenClearyArchive/Nito.KitchenSink/blob/d5f7d6dfdaf6642868ecd4cd81d8c0c90af55ca7/Source/Nito.KitchenSink/Weakness/WeakCollection.cs). The `WeakCollection<T>` class depends on [`WeakReference<T>`](https://github.com/StephenClearyArchive/Nito.KitchenSink/blob/d5f7d6dfdaf6642868ecd4cd81d8c0c90af55ca7/Source/Nito.KitchenSink/Weakness/WeakReference.cs), which in turn depends on [`SafeGCHandle`](https://github.com/StephenClearyArchive/Nito.KitchenSink/blob/d5f7d6dfdaf6642868ecd4cd81d8c0c90af55ca7/Source/Nito.KitchenSink/Weakness/_internal/SafeGCHandle.cs).

Comment: @stephen-cleary - this doesn't appear to be in your most recent source, so I am curious on how you are approaching this problem with the latest CLR.

Comment: @Mike-EEE: For ephemerons, I use [Connected Properties](http://connectedproperties.codeplex.com/). They don't support enumeration, but I've never needed that capability.

Comment: The "here" link is dead.

Comment: The link http://nitokitchensink.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/51391#1006413 is dead.  The [archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171225211251/http://nitokitchensink.codeplex.com/releases/view/57091) doesn't include the source or binaries.

Comment: Links have been fixed.

Answer (score 9):

You could easily implement a `WeakList<T>` class, which would wrap a `List<WeakReference>`.

There is no way to automatically remove objects when they are garbage collected, because it's not possible to detect when this happens. However, you could remove "dead" (garbage collected) objects when you encounter them, by checking the `WeakReference.IsAlive` property. However, I wouldn't recommend this approach, because it could lead to confusing behavior from the client's point of view. Instead, I would recommend implementing a `Purge` method to remove dead entries, that you would call explicitly.

Here's a sample implementation :

```
public class WeakList<T> : IList<T>
{
    private List<WeakReference<T>> _innerList = new List<WeakReference<T>>();

    #region IList<T> Members

    public int IndexOf(T item)
    {
        return _innerList.Select(wr => wr.Target).IndexOf(item);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, T item)
    {
        _innerList.Insert(index, new WeakReference<T>(item));
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        _innerList.RemoveAt(index);
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return _innerList[index].Target;
        }
        set
        {
            _innerList[index] = new WeakReference<T>(value);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region ICollection<T> Members

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        _innerList.Add(new WeakReference<T>(item));
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _innerList.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        return _innerList.Any(wr => object.Equals(wr.Target, item));
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        _innerList.Select(wr => wr.Target).CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return _innerList.Count; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        int index = IndexOf(item);
        if (index > -1)
        {
            RemoveAt(index);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable<T> Members

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _innerList.Select(x => x.Target).GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable Members

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion

    public void Purge()
    {
        _innerList.RemoveAll(wr => !wr.IsAlive);
    }
}
```

This class uses the following classes and extension methods :

**`WeakReference<T>`** (just a strongly typed wrapper around `WeakReference`)

```
[Serializable]
public class WeakReference<T> : WeakReference
{
    public WeakReference(T target)
        : base(target)
    {
    }

    public WeakReference(T target, bool trackResurrection)
        : base(target, trackResurrection)
    {
    }

    public WeakReference(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        : base(info, context)
    {
    }

    public new T Target
    {
        get
        {
            return (T)base.Target;
        }
    }
}
```

**`IndexOf`** (same as `IList<T>.IndexOf`, but works on a `IEnumerable<T>`)

```
    public static int IndexOf<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, T item)
    {
        var entry = source.Select((x, i) => new { Value = x, Index = i })
                    .Where(x => object.Equals(x.Value, item))
                    .FirstOrDefault();
        return entry != null ? entry.Index : -1;
    }
```

**`CopyTo`** (same as `IList<T>.CopyTo`, but works on a `IEnumerable<T>`)

```
    public static void CopyTo<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, T[] array, int startIndex)
    {
        int lowerBound = array.GetLowerBound(0);
        int upperBound = array.GetUpperBound(0);
        if (startIndex < lowerBound)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("startIndex", "The start index must be greater than or equal to the array lower bound");
        if (startIndex > upperBound)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("startIndex", "The start index must be less than or equal to the array upper bound");

        int i = 0;
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            if (startIndex + i > upperBound)
                throw new ArgumentException("The array capacity is insufficient to copy all items from the source sequence");
            array[startIndex + i] = item;
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It would be possible in .net 4.0 to design a list structure which would automatically remove objects that are GC'ed by using a `ConditionalWeakTable` to attach the objects in the list to other objects with finalizers would perform the removal.  Note that this should not be done with a numerically-indexed list (since there's no way to accomplish removal in thread-safe fashion) but it could be done with a linked list that iterates things in order or reverse order of creation.  I'm not sure, though, in what cases actively removing references as they become dead...

Comment: ...would be better than keeping a count of how many items have been added since the last purge, and how many were alive at that time, and doing a purge when the number of items added since the last one exceeds the number that were alive then (or, alternatively, every time an item is added, scan a few items for removal, keeping track of one's position in the list and restarting at the beginning when appropriate).  Such approach would at any given time keep some `WeakReference` objects needlessly in scope, but the number would be bounded relative to the number that were alive as of the last GC.

Comment: @supercat Considered, but unfortunately finalizers come with extra memory+performance costs and they will run from a background thread and thereby require you to do locking or use thread safe collections... (more overheads)

Comment: There also exists a default generic implementation for `WeakReference<T>` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712738%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @ChieltenBrinke, indeed, but it didn't exist when I wrote this answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

For anybody needing to use a ConditionalWeakTable in .NET 2.0 or 3.5 there is a backport of it here: https://github.com/theraot/Theraot/wiki/Features

Comment: Hi Patrick. Just saw your post. As far as I read the docs of the ConditionalWeakTable is does not keep necessarily keep the references even is there is a strong reference to the object from the outside. Do you have other informations?

Answer (score -3):

How about using a java.util.WeakHashMap and storing your objects in the keys? The value can be any dummy object. You can only get WeakSet functionality, though, as the Map isn't ordered.

Comment: The question is tagged .net, so java doesn't help.